# Android Proguard ExceptionInInitializerError and RuntimeException

Tags: android, gson, obfuscation, proguard

I want to obfuscate my .apk and I'm having some troubles with Proguard. Using eclipse I've enabled this:

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

I'm using 4 external libs:

- android-support-v4.jar
- nine-old-android-lib.jar
- gson-2.2.2.jar
- commons-io-2.4.jar

I guess I'm having trouble with gson:

```
private static Type MY_DATA_TYPE = new TypeToken<Pair<Map<Point, Void>, Integer>>() {}.getType();
```

Every time I use it:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at com.myapp.MyActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)

...

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing type parameter.
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.getSuperclassTypeParameter(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using this options but I guess it wont help:

```
-keepattributes Exceptions, InnerClasses, *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-libraryjars .../libs/android-support-v4.jar
-libraryjars .../libs/nine-old-android-lib.jar
-libraryjars .../libs/gson-2.2.2.jar
-libraryjars .../libs/commons-io-2.4.jar


-keep class java.** { *; }
-keep class android.** { *; }
-keep class org.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
-keep class com.nineoldandroids.** { *; }
```

How can I solve this and create an obfuscated .apk that works properly?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am using... Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Station>>>() { }.getType(); .. which does give me this list but i get Station object null what should i do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Guess this is a gson "problem", here's the solution:

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

Thanks to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-gson/6XuHfOoZIKo

Comment: I am using... Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Station>>>() { }.getType(); .. which does give me this list but i get Station object null what should i do

Comment: Create a new topic with your question and some code examples and error output so we can give you some quality help.

Comment: yes i did create a one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539960/how-to-get-release-build-apk-file-using-proguard, apparently i can't get the explanation about what is going wrong and how to fix it

Comment: But you have marked that question as "answered". If it's not solved remove the "answered" check.

Answer (score 1):

Proguard configuration as shown by google gson proguard example.

[google gson proguard configuration link](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
```